# Spark Scala Reading JSON as One Column

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

```
OS X El Capitan 10.11.6
Spark 2.2.0
Scala 2.11.8
```

The specific JSON file that I am trying to read into Spark can be found [here](https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20%28select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places%281%29%20where%20text%3D%22New%20York%2C%20NY%22%29&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys).

When I use the code below, it provides a single column output of what looks like all the column values together:

```
val test = spark.read.format("json").load("Downloads/yql.json")
test.show()

+--------------------+
|               query|
+--------------------+
|[1,2017-11-08T12:...|
+--------------------+
```

However, running `test.printSchema()` returns an appropriately nested JSON-formatted schema.

How do I read this file into Spark so that the JSON file is transformed into a DataFrame with multiple columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My issue was not understanding the requirements of how to extract fields from nested arrays (both Array and Struct). Of course, after posting this question, I ran across [this post](http://xinhstechblog.blogspot.com/2016/05/reading-json-nested-array-in-spark.html) which helped a lot.

Here is an example of how I can view the 10-day forecast in a DataFrame from the data source I included in the question:

```
val test = spark.read.format("json").load("Downloads/yql.json")

val testFinal = test.
    select(
        "query.created",
        "query.results.channel.item.lat",
        "query.results.channel.item.long",
        "query.results.channel.units.temperature",
        "query.results.channel.item.forecast").
    withColumn("forecast_explode", explode($"forecast")).
    withColumn("date", $"forecast_explode.date").
    withColumn("forecast_high", $"forecast_explode.high").
    withColumn("forecast_low", $"forecast_explode.low").
    drop($"forecast").
    drop($"forecast_explode")

testFinal.show() 

+--------------------+--------+----------+-----------+-----------+-------------+------------+
|             created|     lat|      long|temperature|       date|forecast_high|forecast_low|
+--------------------+--------+----------+-----------+-----------+-------------+------------+
|2017-11-08T14:57:15Z|40.71455|-74.007118|          F|08 Nov 2017|           48|          39|
|2017-11-08T14:57:15Z|40.71455|-74.007118|          F|09 Nov 2017|           52|          39|
|2017-11-08T14:57:15Z|40.71455|-74.007118|          F|10 Nov 2017|           47|          27|
|2017-11-08T14:57:15Z|40.71455|-74.007118|          F|11 Nov 2017|           40|          25|
|2017-11-08T14:57:15Z|40.71455|-74.007118|          F|12 Nov 2017|           48|          33|
|2017-11-08T14:57:15Z|40.71455|-74.007118|          F|13 Nov 2017|           51|          45|
|2017-11-08T14:57:15Z|40.71455|-74.007118|          F|14 Nov 2017|           53|          43|
|2017-11-08T14:57:15Z|40.71455|-74.007118|          F|15 Nov 2017|           52|          39|
|2017-11-08T14:57:15Z|40.71455|-74.007118|          F|16 Nov 2017|           54|          43|
|2017-11-08T14:57:15Z|40.71455|-74.007118|          F|17 Nov 2017|           54|          44|
+--------------------+--------+----------+-----------+-----------+-------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the schema of json data using:

```
val dataDF = spark.read.option("samplingRatio", "1.0").json("test.json")
```

Use the schema for applying while reading json file:

```
val test =spark.read.schema(dataDF.schema).json("test.json")
```

Now, you can use it to query specific columns of json:

```
test.select($"query.lang").show
+-----+
| lang|
+-----+
|en-us|
+-----+
```